# PHP json_decode not working - displays NULL output

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to use JSON decode to retrieve some information but it's not working, it's just showing the data as null when I use var_dump

Here's the JSON formatted data passed in the URL

```
orderSummary={"orderInfo":[{"itemNumber":"1","quantity":"3","price":"5.99","productName":"Item_B"}]}
```

When I simply echo the un-decoded string I get the following

```
echo $_GET['orderSummary'];
//displays the following
{\"orderInfo\":[{\"itemNumber\":\"1\",\"quantity\":\"3\",\"price\":\"5.99\",\"productName\":\"Item_B\"}]}
```

However, when I try to decode it the result is null

```
$order = $_GET['orderSummary'];
$data = json_decode($order,true);
echo "<PRE>";
var_dump($data); die();
//displays the following
<PRE>NULL
```

Is it not properly formatted?

Comment: Don't you see those backslashes? Doesn't it confuse you, that you have passed the data without backticks but then they appear? Do you think that after adding some random characters (backticks in this case) JSON would still be valid?

Comment: Disable `magic_quotes_gpc` in your `php.ini`.

Answer (score 14):

Run the input string through [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) first.

```
$input = '{\"orderInfo\":[{\"itemNumber\":\"1\",\"quantity\":\"3\",\"price\":\"5.99\",\"productName\":\"Item_B\"}]}';

print_r(json_decode(stripslashes($input)));
```

**Output**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [orderInfo] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [itemNumber] => 1
                    [quantity] => 3
                    [price] => 5.99
                    [productName] => Item_B
                )

        )

)
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/OuwzkyjX)

**Alternatively**

Turn off [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc). Considering that it has been deprecated (and removed in 5.4), **this the better option**.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Any idea why the slashes appeared? I've used JSON_decode before but I've never had this happen.

Comment: The slashes are added before quotes in GET/POST data if you have `magic_quotes_gpc` turned on in your PHP.ini. You should turn this off, as this feature is deprecated.